# In IPython, why does the Exclamation Mark (!) not work as a command line entry?

Tags: python, command-line, anaconda, ipython

I understand (at least according to the textbook I am using) that in IPython, it is possible to run command line codes using the exclamation mark (!). So for example:

`!pwd` should result in `/Users/my/current/working/directory`

However, when I type this code, I get the following response:

`'pwd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Instead, if I type `pwd`, then I do indeed get `'C:\\Users\\myworkingdirectory'`

Could there be something wrong with my installation? (Or is the textbook wrong)?

I am using ipython having installed anaconda on a standard windows machine.

Comment: `pwd` is recognized as a powershell command, but not as a regular cmd command. your ipython is probably using cmd to execute terminal commands when using the `!` prefix

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I was having similar trouble with !ls. The textbook I'm working off seems to make out that these commands should work with !, but they don't. It could well be an error with the textbook